# c# azure devops repo builder has stopped working suddenly

Tags: c#, azure, devops

So I wrote a little c# utility which connects to my devops azure repo and downloads a bunch of files in a zip, then unpacks the zip file(s) and then does a text search and replace to customise the files.

This utility was working fine up to Friday 8th. On Monday 11th the utility started telling me i was unauthorised.

This utility is used by 3 other colleagues and it is still working a-ok for them, just not me :(

The utility has been working fine for over 4 months until his week.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ########.######.####.#######
{
class Program
{
    const String c_collectionUri = "https://dev.azure.com/#################";
    const String c_projectName = "########.######.#######.######.#########";
    const String c_variableGroupId = "########-####-####-####-############"; // id for the LIVE project / repos
    const String download_dir = @"C:\###########\";

    const String dev_short_name_txt = "$$dev_shortname$$";
    const String dev_long_name_txt = "$$dev_long_name$$";
    const String todays_date_txt = "$$todays_date$$";

    static System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection log = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

    private static string dev_short_name;
    private static string dev_long_name;
    private static string todays_date;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // gets just the username, e.g. ############
        dev_short_name = Environment.UserName;
        Console.WriteLine("Who are you : " + dev_short_name);

        DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // As DateTime
        todays_date = today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // As String
        Console.WriteLine("Today is    : " + todays_date);

        // Interactively ask the user for credentials, caching them so the user isn't constantly prompted
        VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
        creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

        // Connect to Azure DevOps Services
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), creds);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Projects....");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
        TeamHttpClient teamClient = connection.GetClient<TeamHttpClient>();
        // Call to get the list of projects
        IEnumerable<TeamProjectReference> projects = projectClient.GetProjects().Result;
        Dictionary<TeamProjectReference, IEnumerable<WebApiTeam>> results = new Dictionary<TeamProjectReference, IEnumerable<WebApiTeam>>();

        // Iterate over the returned projects
        foreach (var project in projects)
        {
            // Get the teams for the project
            IEnumerable<WebApiTeam> teams = teamClient.GetTeamsAsync(project.Name).Result;

            // Add the project/teams item to the results dictionary
            results.Add(project, teams);
            Console.WriteLine(" " + project.Id + " " + project.Name);
```

Here's the error output:

```
Who are you : ###############
Today is    : 14/07/2022

Projects....
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Unauthorized
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<HandleResponseAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__56.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<EnsureConnectedAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<CheckForServerUpdatesAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<FindServiceDefinitionAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<LocationForCurrentConnectionAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.<ResolveLocationDataAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.<GetLocationDataAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.<GetClientInstanceAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.<GetClientServiceImplAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.<GetClientAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]()
   at ########.######.####.#######.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\########\########.######.####.#######\########.######.####.#######\Program.cs:line 60
```

I've googled around and tried various things like:

- deleting C:\Users\###########\AppData\Local.IdentityService
- clearing temp internet files / folders from both Edge and Chrome
- removing all generic credetials from the Credential Manager
- using alternatives to VssCredentials / VssClientCredentialStorage / VssConnection like:

  ```
       // Interactively ask the user for credentials, caching them so the user isn't constantly prompted
       VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
       creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

       Console.WriteLine("creds    : " + creds.Windows.ToString());
       Console.WriteLine("creds2   : " + creds.Storage.ToString());

       // Connect to Azure DevOps Services
       VssConnection connection;
       ProjectHttpClient projectClient;
       try
       {
           connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), creds);
           projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
       }
       catch (VssServiceResponseException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(e);
           connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), new VssAadCredential());
           //connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));
           //connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), new VssBasicCredential("##############","###################################"));
           projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
       }

       //VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), creds);
       //VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), new VssAadCredential());
  ```

But I still can't get in!!!

I'm not aware of any changes being made to my device.

Answer (score 0):

Our IT guys fixed this one. I was missing a trusted site setting, which they've added via a browser GPO for edge / chrome.

:)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).